# JavaScript Visualization library for time series providing aggregation feature

Tags: javascript, json, graph, time-series, aggregate

I've some JSON data like:

```
{"data": [
  {"timestamp": 1527481579, "amount": 1},
  {"timestamp": 1527481579, "amount": 3},
  {"timestamp": 1527481518, "amount": 2},
  {"timestamp": 1527481518, "amount": 3}
]}
```

Next, I would like to produce a bar chart which show me the sum of "amount" per time interval (e.g. per minute):

```
Monday, 28-May-18 04:26 - 4
Monday, 28-May-18 04:25 - 5
```

Since the time interval shall be dynamically chosen by the user (e.g. hour, day, week, month) I'm searching a JS visualization library which provides automatic aggregation of time series data.

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: `I'm searching a JS visualization library` - use google, not stack overflow ... *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*

Comment: d3,highcharts,chartjs... so many are there

Comment: Even your `json` is invalid.